# WAMP doesn't update html file after editing

Tags: php, html, apache, wamp

i have another question. I am using WAMP as my local server. I have this file index.htm. The problem now is when I try to edit this file and reload localhost in the browser nothing' changed. But when i double click the html file to open it without WAMP server it diplays the edited one. I don't know why..

Comment: are you sure wamp's showing the file you think it's showing?

Comment: Wamp is showing me the old file which does not exists anymore.

Comment: I know your html is that.. An html file, however, just humor me, and put /?t=123 on the end of the url.

Answer (score 2):

it's working now. I only have to put all files inside WWW folder and not inside another folder. Thanks everybody for the help..

Comment: You can put files in subfolders under `www`. Just update your URL to reflect the location of the file, i.e. `http://localhost/index.htm` => `http://localhost/myfolder/index.htm`

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that the index.htm is in the correct (WAMP) directory (usually c:\wamp\www)
2. Check WAMP is running

Personally i use XAMPP for mac (they have a windows version too) and place your Websites in /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/ and access them via (http://localhost/) or you put your Websites in the Sites-Folder in your Home and access them via (http://localhost/~username/).

Obviously if you use windows the paths will be different, but XAMPP will provide you with a help screen on first boot.

Comment: it's inside WWW folder. I tried many times to reload it but nothing's changed. :-(